# Call load balancer ARN in CF template that itself launches the load balancer

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a simple CF template that launches an ec2 instance and a load balancer and sets up listener rule in the CF template. I am having an issue when configuring HTTPListener that the HTTPListener needs the arn of the load balancer which is still being made and I cannot provide it.

```html
    HTTPlistener:
   Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
   DependsOn: ElasticLoadBalancer
   Properties:
     DefaultActions:
       - Type: fixed-response
         FixedResponseConfig:
           ContentType: text/plain
           MessageBody: Success
           StatusCode: '200'
     LoadBalancerArn: 
       !GetAtt ElasticLoadBalancer.LoadBalancerArn
     Port: '443'
     Protocol: HTTPS
     Certificates:
       - CertificateArn: >-
```

I have tried `!GetAtt ElasticLoadBalancer.LoadBalancerArn` but it does not seem to work. Would someone be able to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ARN, you [only need](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values) to use `Ref`:

```
     LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ElasticLoadBalancer
```